# Copy FontAwesome icon

Tags: angular, font-awesome

I am creating a breadcrumb component in Angular2 with fontawesome icon (chevron-right) as separator and I want to copy the breadcrumb data using standard select and ctrl+c. 
 Now when I copy the text it does not copy icon.
So the data when pasted contains only the text. For e.g.

If below is my breadcrumb
A > B > C

When i copy and paste it, i get only
A   B   C

Is there any way to achieve this (like 'alt' in img tag), rather than manually handling it in Angular2?

Answer (score 0):

add this in between you A B C

```
<i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

and don't forget to install fontawesome in angular 2 project either using npm install or you can add this cdn in index.html file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
```

Comment: @himanshu have you installed fontawsome in you project ? can you show your code. because i am doing same . and it works for me

Comment: Were you able to copy the text and paste it with > icon? Due to some restriction i can not share the code.

Comment: can you just add this cdn link in your index.html file .. <link> put in <head> tag not in body tag.

Comment: for me its working. i just added <link> in my head tag in angular 2 project. no need to install using npm . just add this cdn that will be sufficent.

Comment: @himanshu i added simple code in plnkr. here is the link https://plnkr.co/edit/VUCrTnUI54zSXcLsl0SU?p=preview

Comment: In the plnkr also, when i copy and paste the text in say notepad or word, i get A  B  C rather than required A > B > C.

Comment: @himanshu  is my plnkr showing that output you want when you open that website?. its not showing in your machine because you didn't install fontawsome properly. or there may be some other issue. but if you not share some code how would i find out the issue.